# Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_8' (type Sequential): • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 28), dtype=int32) • training=False

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have created a Tensorflow model with some dense layers and with the input size as 28x28
When I try to use `model.predict()` and input a 28x28 numpy array, it gives me an error.

Here is the model(everything is imported correctly):

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(Flatten(input_shape = (28,28)))
model.add(Dense(64,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(36,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(18,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ['accuracy'])
training = model.fit(tf.expand_dims(pixels1, axis=-1), labels1, epochs = 10
```

Now if I tried to predict on a np.zeros() array with the 28x28 shape:

```
model.predict(np.zeros((28,28)).astype('int32'))
```

I get an error saying

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "c:\Users\sandi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2440, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "c:\Users\sandi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2425, in step_function  **
...
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_8' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 28), dtype=int32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Comment: This is not the complete error message.